# Load Image programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an ImageView. This is the code I am using to add image to the ImageView

```
 var imgstr = pf["ImageFileName"] as String
 image = UIImage(named: imgstr)!
 println(imgstr) //the output here is abc.png
 self.Imageview.image = image
```

Now I have the image in my Project folder as you can see in the screenshot[image: Screenshot]

Still I am getting this error at run time

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Can you check the image `abc.png` is listing under __Build Phases -> Copy bundle resources__ ?

Comment: Could self.ImageView be nil? Did you properly set it up? If you're using Storyboard, is the referencing outlet properly set?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add your images to Images.xcassets

[image]

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"abc")
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"abc") {
   imageView?.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
self.Imageview!.image = image
```

instead of

```
self.Imageview.image = image
```